# Where is the treasure generation table mentioned in Buffalo Castle?

Tags: published-adventures, treasure, solo, tunnels-and-trolls

I have 7th edition of *Tunnels and Trolls* (30th anniversary edition) and I am playing the "Buffalo Castle" solo adventure. I defeated a wandering monster and rolled for treasure, which the adventure tells me to roll from the treasure generation table in the rules.

However, the rules do not have a treasure generation table, as far as I see.

Supposing I am not just critically failing at my book reading saving throw, where can I find a suitable table? Maybe the table existed in older editions, for example; this would be nice to know, though I do not have them.

Answer (score 3):

The treasure generation can be found at least in the fifth edition rulebook, section 3.2.

The fourth edition also seems to have treasure generation tables.

Such tables do not exist in the first edition.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I asked elsewhere and got an answer. But please give a better one, if you have it.

Comment: No worries. I'd just located my copy and came back when I saw you'd self-answered. I can't think of anything to add. Good work!